# Margin Overflow From Parent in CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

Whenever I add margin to any element I get overflow, I tried adding box-sizing, position:relative. but nothing works

searched on google but nothing seems to help me

can anyone know why is this happening?

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IvBi.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add margin to a div that is a sibling of your container or else it'll create an overflow. Use padding instead. See how the text in the margin example shifts the text.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.padding-example {
  padding: 10px;
}

.margin-example {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="padding-example">Correct</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="margin-example">Wrong</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats explain it. I removed margin from child and added padding to parent

Answer (score 3):

The margin is *outside*  the element. One way to deal with it is to use `calc` on `width` as in the following snippet.

And note that margin is diferent from padding: `padding`is *inside*  the border (so it is included in the area covered by the background color), margin is *outside*:

```css
.x {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 30px;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  background: yellow;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">margin....</div>
```

With `padding` instead of `margin`, this would be:

```css
.x {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">Padding....</div>
```